# Deleting printed content in PHP mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a site to upload content and I want the user to be able to delete content on their Edit page. The following code is what I have echoed after the user inputs their content

```
<div id="content_review">
<?php
$q_getRev = "SELECT * FROM REVIEWS ORDER BY RID DESC";
$r_getRev = mysql_query($q_getRev, $connection);
$n_getRev = mysql_num_rows($r_getRev);
for ($i = 0; $i < $n_getRev; $i++) {
    echo '<img class="poster" src="'
        . mysql_result($r_getRev, $i, 'PREVIEW_IMG') . ' " />';
    echo '<div class="title">'
        . mysql_result($r_getRev, $i, 'TITLE') . '</div><br/>';
    echo '<div class="reviews">'
        . mysql_result($r_getRev, $i, 'REVIEW') . '</div>';
    echo '<div><img src=image/x.png id="delete">'
        . mysql_result($_delRev, $i, 'REVIEW') . '</div>';
}
?>
```

I want the user to be able to delete content that was previously printed in PHP. I'm not entirely sure how to proceed to make the following line delete content from my REVIEW column from mysql (the following line appears as a delete button next to the already printed content)

```
echo '<div><img src=image/x.png id="delete">'
    . mysql_result($_delRev, $i, 'REVIEW').'</div>';
```

Comment: Suggestion, [**Don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0):

That line should be:

```
echo '<div><a href="delete_content.php?rid=' . mysql_result($r_getRev, $i, 'RID') . '"><img src="image/x.png"></a></div>';
```

Then you need to write a `delete_content.php` script that deletes the content whose RID is equal to `$_GET['rid']`. The PHP in that script should be something like:

```
$rid = intval($_GET['rid');
$delRev = "DELETE FROM REVIEWS WHERE RID = $rid";
```

Also notice that I removed the `id="remove"` attribute from the `<img>` tag. IDs have to be unique, but you were using the same ID for each item. I doubt you need an ID on the image tags, so I just removed it.

Comment: No, your PHP makes no sense. I've added some sample PHP in my answer.